# Show Dialog using PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-alarms, android-event

I am working on Calender Events reminder . There is no native Calender events reminder in Android so user install different calender apps.

Now these apps can be different on reminding events like on reminder notifications can be shown. Now I want that I set an event programmatically in these event calender apps and on time reached not show any notification rather a pop up message will be shown with alarm like sound. At that I using a code from that site . Its working but it showing reminders in form of notifications.

Here is code:

OnReceive

```
void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
    Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderEditActivity.class); 
    notificationIntent.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId); 

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

    Notification note=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), System.currentTimeMillis());
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_title), getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), pi);
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 


    int id = (int)((long)rowId);
    mgr.notify(id, note);
}
```

Now I want to show a dialog box instead of notification so how it can be possible from using these lines of code that this pending intent should be used in dialogue box.

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderEditActivity.class); 
notificationIntent.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId); 

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your **Receiver class**, just code to get the dialog to display instead of Notification.

**Class that displays Dialog:**

```
public class AlarmDialogPopUp extends Activity
{

    private int m_alarmId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the alarm ID from the intent extra data
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            m_alarmId = extras.getInt("AlarmID", -1);
        } else {
            m_alarmId = -1;
        }

        // Show the popup dialog
        showDialog(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        super.onCreateDialog(id);

        // Build the dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("ALARM REMINDER");
        alert.setMessage("Its time for the alarm ");
        alert.setCancelable(false);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                AlarmDialogPopUp.this.finish();
            }
        });

        // Create and return the dialog
        AlertDialog dlg = alert.create();

        return dlg;
    }
}
```

**In your `onReceive` to show dialog :**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
          // Launch the alarm popup dialog
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

            alarmIntent.setClass(context, AlarmDialogPopUp .class);
            alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Pass on the alarm ID as extra data
            alarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmID", intent.getIntExtra("AlarmID", -1));

            // Start the popup activity
            context.startActivity(alarmIntent);

    }
```

**EDIT based on the comment:**

To play sound, you need to make use of MediaPlayer like below.

Add this line in the `onCreate()` of `AlarmDialogPopUp` activity class to play the sound.

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer; //global variable.

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alarmsound);
```

Add the below lines in the `onClick()` of the dialog to stop the sound:

```
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.release();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. If i want to show sounds when dialog is shown

Comment: You deserve more than +1...Thanks.