# Show alarm popup in android

Tags: android

there

I have a system in android OS,scenario is :

when phone get some SMS that make phone alarm until user stop alarm that appear above of all running app,please show me what is the best pattern to do that?

1)I get sms with broadcast receiver

2)Run the service to play sound and show popup with some kind message

3)Stop the alarm with popup alarm shower.

some body help me about what kind of popup is the best solution for

1-Play sound? (Audio-manager,....)

2-popup? (alarm-manager,Notification,...)

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate :)- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874144/show-dialoge-using-pending-intent-in-android

Comment: I suggest use AlarmManager and Notification its best way.